# XOR operand on two strings in python?

Tags: python, hex, xor

I am trying to use the XOR operation using two strings in python.

Here is my script:

```
packet = "277500011200".decode("hex")
xor = codecs.decode(xor, 'hex')

print packet ^ xor
```

the xor variable is supposed to be basically a key, where if I xor them together they will decode the packet. However, it is telling me that they are both strings. How do I change the type to hex so that they can work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int("ff048deadbeef", 16)` converts from hex to int.

Edit: seems like OP intended to use `x.decode(codec)` before converting.

Comment: I've done that, but now I get this error: invalid literal for int() with base 16:

Comment: `invalid literal for int() with base 16:` what?

Comment: Could you paste here the particular string that gives that error?

Comment: packet = "27750001120007023e12a4f67b12482fb389f8f4a575f4e686fe6305d892d5dda87045864462bf78cfb03f7ce511259a29997d9d7a994db56d13503e643f0dfb3d4e5c7b5b12f0296e26316ff2be4009dd9e935d1357fa49f1af49df7edd6594c2a62b0d786c6b3ccecf8619355b4710c3af163afcf2e6351de55ae9fdd80fae9855952edbd220958c4292582476e29adeb95a634008d6fdd966a147584d8e0646c6bb4292a6847577a1b4a7114848eb1d7b93a12f7a935e9277e14905f25a24677511922f2306973bda16d26f03c78efda934070a693e532d9e7e09d822597836b911a557d55e7d3540a1aa357938990c6fbeb81f63393c85bff1e50e9893b4db547152e4bedfb8ddbddb0ae1eb314c70608ead310db4cc6f".decode("hex")